# UI label wont align properly in iOS 6/iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c

I created the applications using  Xcode 5[IOS 7].I used the custom font for this applications.
While i run the application in IOS 7 the label alignment good.But when i run the same application IOS 6 the label alignment wont align properly.

iOS 7

[image]

iOS 6.
[image]

kindly give me the solutions.

Comment: Where are the images, Sir ??

Comment: No images..!! Edit ur ques..

Comment: He can't post the Images due to low reputation.

Comment: At least there should be a link.

Comment: Put your images as a link one of us will edit your question.

Comment: getting some problem while uploading the images..The stack overflow says "at least 10 reputation"

Comment: i have attached the Link for that image mentioned above. http://www.exarcplus.com/production/images/ios_6.png    http://www.exarcplus.com/production/images/ios_7.png

Comment: Are you setting frame of label in xib or programatically?

Comment: am setting frame in xib

Answer (score 0):

You have to go with below step:

**step (1)**

- Uncheck mark Autolayout field.

[image]

**step (2)**

- From your nib file set value of that UILable is: "Y" = -20;

[image]

may be it will help.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is pretty much weird but has a simple solution.I had been facing the same problem too.

Click on the label and then autoresize it by clicking Command key icon ⌘ (Command key) and the   =  (equal to) sign together.
This should autofit the label.